# How many cubic (i.e., third-degree) polynomials $f(x)$ are there such that $f(x)$ has positive integer coefficients and $f(1)=9$?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, cubics

How many cubic (i.e., third-degree) polynomials $f(x)$ are there such that $f(x)$ has positive integer coefficients and $f(1)=9$? (Note: all coefficients must be positive---coefficients are not permitted to be 0, so for example $f(x) = x^3 + 8$ is not a valid polynomial.)

I can't list all of them and I need a 1-1 correspondence, which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: The polynomials are a red herring. You have $f(x) = ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + d$ evaluated at $1$, which is just $a + b + c + d$. You're looking for the number of ways to write $9$ as the sum of four ordered positive integers.

Comment: @EricTressler yeah, but then you still might have to check which permutations of coefficients are cubic-polynomially equivalent

Comment: @EricTressler And just to illustrate how much of a red herring it is, you bring the terms of the polynomial in "mixed" order (the terms are not ordered by degree).

Comment: @Jeppe Stigg Nielson -- the coefficients are ordered purely by reason of each being that of its respective term - what order they are _presented_ in is immaterial. ¶ _Eric Tressler_ is perfectly correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Lorenzo -- how would two different permutations of coefficients yield the same polynomial? ¶ _Eric Tressler_ is perfectly correct, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the number of $(a,b,c,d)\in\left(\mathbb{Z}^+\right)^4$ such that $a+b+c+d=9$ is given by the coefficient of $x^9$ in the product $(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^4$, i.e. by
$$ [x^9]\frac{x^4}{(1-x)^4} = [x^5]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=[x^5]\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n =\binom{5+3}{3}=\color{red}{56}.$$
See also [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: How would I do this question if f(x) has nonnegative integer coefficients instead of just positive coefficients?

Comment: @132479: just replace $x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ with $1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$.

Comment: if x + x^2 + ... is replaced with 1 +x +x^2... , then would n be 6 and 9C3 = 84

Answer (score 1):

Consider polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. In general it looks like $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers. Given is, $f(1) = a+ b+ c+ d = 9$. So the number of such cubic polynomials correspond to the number of positive integer solutions of $a+b+c+d=9$.

EDIT: Apply Balls and sticks method. if $x = a-1, y=b-1, z=c-1, w=d-1$ then the number of positive integer solutions of $(a,b,c,d)$ s.t. $a+b+c+d=9$ are the same as non-negative integer solution of $(x,y,z,w)$ s.t. $x+y+z+w = 9-4=5$. The total number of solutions is $\binom{5+3}{3}$. 
(reference: combinations of multisets) 
Can you do this for nonnegative coefficients?

Comment: I don't think you want $\binom{16}{3}$.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. Thanks for the heads up. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial to the third degree is basically $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. Substituting $1$ into this equation gives $a + b + c + d = 9$. Does this look familiar? Yes, it's stars and bars. Since $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are positive integers, we can say that there are $8$ slots to put the bars and we have to choose three. This is equal to 8 C 3. Simplifying, we get $56$ as our final answer.